# PHP switch() statement

Tags: php

Is this good practise ... ie, grouping the default case with another?

```
    switch ($cond){
            case 1:
                ...;
                break;
            case 2:
                ...;
                break;
            case 3:
            default:
                ...;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing it... nothing wrong at all.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with that!

Comment: It is *not a bad practice*. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: A comment to indicate that falling-through is INTENDED would be good, but otherwise there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes perfect sense to do it that way.

Also, @Ian is correct, but in a limited scope. If you wanted additional functionality applied to `case 3` you would leave it the way it is. As long as you don't `break`, it will go on to the next `case`.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of makes `case 3` redundant though, so I'd remove it and just leave it as `default`

Comment: There are times when you want to put that in your code to show that `case 3` might be needed later, but just has the default action now.  It seems like a fine and helpful pointer to me.

Comment: Your answer certainly isn't wrong... but I disagree.  Having `case 3` in there lets the person looking at the code know that there is a `case 3` which, for now, should act like the default case.